# Why would a Java-based simulation program operate at the same speed on a faster computer?

Tags: java, performance, hardware

***Context***

Hi All,
I'm running a program called Firstrate 5 for work - its a simple java program to calculate thermal performance for buildings. After inputting a model the user presses Calculate and it computes the results. Some models are complex, and take in the order of minutes to calculate, which often as part of an iterative process is very time consuming. I had it on good authority that it was likely my old HDD slowing things down. It was time for an upgrade anyway, so I splashed out on a new computer with a SSD, faster CPU, 2x RAM. I was excited to see the performance improvement, so I decided to compare the time required to calculate the same model on my new an old machines. Lo and behold *they both take exactly 3:15 seconds* to calculate.

***Question***

What possible explanations are there for a java program to exhibit equivalent performance on a faster machine? Is this likely something to do with the way the software is coded, or could there be an equivalently sized hardware bottleneck on both systems? Does it have anything to do with the JRE? My main goal is to make the process faster, so any education or pointers you can give me may help me find a solution.

**Old specs** - (Toshiba Laptop Satellite L50-C) , Windows 10

CPU = Intel i7-5500U, 2 Cores @2.4GHz

RAM = 8GB (DDR3, 1600 MHz)

HDD = 5400 RPM

CPU usage during calculation ~ 54%

HDD usage during calculation ~ 20%

RAM usage during calculation ~ 53%

**New specs** - (PC Build), Windows 10

CPU = AMD Ryzen 5 2600X, 6 Cores @3.6 GHz

RAM = 16GB (DDR 4 2400 MHz)

SSD (Samsung 860 EVO)

CPU usage during calculation = 9.7%

HDD usage during calculation = 19%

RAM usage during calculation ~ 0%

Comment: You could probably assign more resources to the JVM, but next to that I am not entirely sure. Are you using third party libraries? Do you access resources, like files, websites, shares and so on? Could it be just your code that is inefficient? As you see there are a lot of factors that can slow your programm down and it is very hard to pin point it down to RAM, FileSystem or CPU. Also how are you measuring time? Have you used a benchmark?

Comment: Looks like it is using only one core. Also constrained by RAM speed. This is only guess, you need to profile it to know for sure.

Comment: @Lino Thanks for your response, I'll look into assigning more resources to the JVM. No third party libraries, no accessing any online databases - just a model file that is run by the program. Also I'm sure the code is very inefficient! I just find it suspicious that it appears equally inefficient on different machines :/

Comment: Does the measured time decrease when you execute your computation in a loop? You have to account for JVM warm up time and JIT, as that can really decrease the execution time of code drastically

Comment: another possibility: the simulation is programmed to run in real time (or a given factor of it), that is, simulated 1 second run in real time 1 second - indicated by less CPU usage on the faster machine - but hard to know without knowing the software

Comment: @talex Yes I don't think it takes advantage of multi-threading. However I would assume some single threading performance improvement, since the new system is running at a faster clock speed? Could very well be constrained by RAM speed, I'll look into whether my old laptop also had DDR4. Perhaps we can rule this out/in.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Good guess, but this would only be the case if every model (regardless of model complexity and on what machine) took the same amount of time, as each model runs over the course of standard climate variations for a year. However a simple model can be calculated in seconds.

Comment: @LNKX clock speed is not so simple. You switched from Intel to AMD. They have different architecture, so you shouldn't expect linear growth in performance (even switch between model of one company doesn't guarantee it).

Comment: or maybe it is a model parameter - some simulation I used had this settings (as fast as posiible, or some factor of real time, mostly for animation)

Comment: @talex I just checked, my laptop only has DDR3 @ 1.6 GHz, while my new PC has DDR4 @ 2.4 GHz, so I'm thinking it might not be a RAM speed issue.

Comment: @talex Hmm, okay that's a fair point about the difference in architecture. I shouldn't expect linear improvements.

Comment: @Lino Unfortunately I'm not able to run the software in a true loop, since I'm not the developer, just a user (I only have the option to hit calculate again after the model finishes computing). However I've found upon multiple subsequent calculations the simulation period remains the same.

Comment: @Lino Also to your first post, no I haven't been using a benchmarking tool (just a stopwatch), I know there are some for devs, but that may not be an option as I can't tamper with the code. Is there some tool that gives metrics for a java program while its operating?

Comment: Ask the vendor of the software.

Comment: @StephenC Yes that's probably the best source of information. However they're so severely understaffed, I've never got any of my support questions answered.

Comment: It seems odd that your HDD usage is quite high in your new test, and your memory is at ~0%. Is your initial heap/max heap too small? Also are you using a 64 bit operating system to make use of that 16gb? I assume you do but just asking...